# Android custom class - Hook into Activity Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I have an activity in which I want to monitor battery life.  I want to decouple the battery life into it's own class.  I could do the following in the activity

```
onPause() {
  batteryChecker = new BatteryChecker();
}
onResume() {
   batteryChecker.kill();
}
```

I would prefer to just do this:

```
onCreate() {
  bg = new BatteryChecker(this);
}
```

Is there any way I can get BatteryChecker to respond to the onPause/onResume of the attached activity?

Comment: Yes-  your first example.  There's no global onPause/onResume framework.  Which is a good thing, because it would be hard to make it work with multiple Activities and Services.

Comment: But there is no way to 'hook into' those callbacks?

Comment: Nope.  You could build one possibly with an event bus or observable or something like that.  But it would be a pain to set up, and dealing with multiple activities could be challenging.

Answer (score 3):

Your `BatteryChecker` can implement `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` and call `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` in `onCreate` when you create your `Application` class, in this case your custom class will receive all Activity lifecycle callbacks.

see more here - [`ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html)

It's of arguable benefit because you still have to use `Activity` events, but you could attach to the `Activity` lifecycle in your activity's `onCreate()` and detach from it in its `onDestroy()` events too.

This may help from a hygiene perspective depending on how "busy" your code is in its existing lifecycle blocks, but doesn't necessarily make it a good practice.

In your `BatteryChecker` class:

```java
public class BatteryChecker implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    private boolean paused = true ;
...
    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(@NonNull Activity activity) {
        if (paused) doResumeStuff();
        paused = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(@NonNull Activity activity) {
        if (!paused) doPauseStuff();
        paused = true;
    }
}
```

And in your activity:

```java
private BatteryChecker batteryChecker = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   batteryChecker = new BatteryChecker();
   getApplication().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(batteryChecker);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   getApplication().unRegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(batteryChecker);
}
```

It should also be noted you'll never see the `onActivityDestroyed()` event fire in your `BatteryChecker` class as its scope is within that of the actual activity's lifecycle.

Comment: Yes, I figured ActivityLifecycleCallbacks were what I need however, calling registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks in the Application class is not helpful.  I see no way of registering it for the BatteryChecker class.

Answer (score 0):

You need a class extends broadcastReceiver

```
 public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
            boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                                status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

            int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
            boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
            boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
        }
    }
```

more info. 
[Monitoring Battery State](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html)

Comment: I am aware of using a BroadcastReceiver  to monitor battery, thanks.  The question is about activity lifecycle hooks though.